# スレッドをタイムスケジュールで終了させるプログラム

Tags: java

制御が出来ません。何がいけないのですか？

```
package com.company;


import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Main  {
    static boolean b = true;
    static Thread stdRun  = null;
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Runnable inputStreamThread = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

                while(b){
                    try{
                        //System.out.println("Thread stdRun start");
                        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                            public void run() {
                                b=false;
                            }
                        };
                        Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
                        timer.schedule(task, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
                        while(true){
                            System.out.println("テスト");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    b=false;
                }

            }

        };

        stdRun = new Thread(inputStreamThread);
            /* スレッドを開始します。 */
        stdRun.start();

            /* スレッドが終了するのを待機 */
        try {
            stdRun.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("スレッドは正常に終了");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

もう少しやりたいことを明確にしていただけると助かるのですが、こういうことでしょうか?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class test {
    static boolean b = true;
    static Thread stdRun  = null;
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Runnable inputStreamThread = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

                try{
                    //System.out.println("Thread stdRun start");
                    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println("run");
                            stdRun.interrupt();
                        }
                    };
                    Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
                    timer.schedule(task, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));

                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println("テスト");
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };

        stdRun = new Thread(inputStreamThread);
            /* スレッドを開始します。 */
        stdRun.start();

            /* スレッドが終了するのを待機 */
        try {
            stdRun.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("スレッドは正常に終了");

    }
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ですが違います。
簡略化するためにwhileの中をtrueにしましたが実際はもっと別の限定的な条件を使ったコードを書いていますだからそこをbに書き換えらてしまうとやりたいことが出来ません。

Comment: @ミント 回答を編集し、`interrupt` にしてみました。

Answer (score 1):

ん…それでは無限ループしますよ？

timer.schedule()　のあとの　while　で無限ループしているので
タイマーが作動しても　while(b)　は一生実行されません。

タイマータスクでスレッドを強制終了（kill）などしているなら話は別ですが、
今回はフラグを変えているだけなので一定時間にフラグを見る処理すなわち

timer.schedule()　の下の　while(true)　は　while(b)　とすべきです。

それだと最初の行の　while(b)　の存在意味がよくわからなくなりますが、なにか事情があるのでしょう